# How to use an angular pipe without transforming anything - just to return a boolean?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am writing a component template that must be disabled under a certain attribute. I am using a function I have defined, called `isDisabled`.

```
isDisabled(){
    //do work here
    //return boolean value
}
```

in my template, I have it like so:

```
<item [disabled]="isDisabled(menuOption)">
```

I recently got a PR comment telling me to change this function into a pipe as it won't have to be reloaded whenever a change detection occurs and slow down the website. He then went on vacation so I cannot ask him.

I thought pipes were only used for transforming data? What did he mean by writing a pipe to do this? So far, what I have done is create a pipe that takes 4 parameters, and I am calling it like this:

```
[disabled]=" ''| myPipe:parameter1:parameter2:parameter3:parameter4"
```

which is working just fine, it's just that I have not seen this done anywhere else in the codebase.
Is this okay? Or am I crazy for creating a pipe like this? And does anyone know what my coworker was talking about?

Keeping a component variable seems difficult because the function takes a parameter and that is how it knows whether or not to return true or false - i.e. if the parameter is of a certain value, then return true in a secnario, otherwise return false:

```
isDisabled(menuOption){
    if (book.isLocked) {
    return true;
    }
    return ((menuOption === 'Delete') && this.isDeleteDisabled);
  }
```

MenuOption here being the selected option that the user clicks on the page.
Thanks

Comment: Your coworker is kinda correct, it is bad practice to do function calls from a template - however, it depends a bit on the amount of work that has to happen in the function (can you explain what is in there?). A pipe there also looks a bit strange I must say.. why not simply set a component variable isDisabled?

Comment: I see - I didn't think about setting a variable, that makes sense - Will setting a component variable fix the issue he originally brought up about having the instance getting called every time a change detection is triggered?

Comment: Yes. Because angular knows when a variable is updated, but it doesn’t know if the return value of a function call has changed (that’s why angular calls the function at every cd cycle which is the problem).

Comment: I have updated the question with the logic that happens in the function. I think keeping a variable is hard here because the function depends on which option in the dropdown was selected (it takes a parameter).

Comment: I assume there is some kind of event triggered if the menu option changes? The trick with setting these things up is thinking in events (or streams if you're into RxJs - which you should be really ;-)). A user usually does 'something' in the system that causes changes. I can't give you other advice then that without seeing the entire component I guess?

Comment: What is happening is I am checking if the current option is disabled based off what the option is. The options are all in a list, and i'm checking if each option is disabled based off the option name - hence the parameter. Each option has a different reason to be disabled or not. Hope that clears some things up